# Python multiprocessing pool inside daemon process

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, multiprocessing, pool

I opened up a question for this problem and did not get a thorough enough answer to solve the issue (most likely due to a lack of rigor in explaining my issues which is what I am attempting to correct): [Zombie process in python multiprocessing daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428842/zombie-process-in-python-multiprocessing-daemon)

I am trying to implement a python daemon that uses a pool of workers to executes commands using `Popen`. I have borrowed the basic daemon from http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

I have only changed the `init`, `daemonize` (or equally the `start`) and `stop` methods. Here are the changes to the `init` method:

```
def __init__(self, pidfile):
#, stdin='/dev/null', stdout='STDOUT', stderr='STDOUT'):
    #self.stdin = stdin
    #self.stdout = stdout
    #self.stderr = stderr
    self.pidfile = pidfile
    self.pool = Pool(processes=4)
```

I am not setting stdin, stdout and stderr so that I can debug the code with print statements. Also, I have tried moving this pool around to a few places but this is the only place that does not produce exceptions.

Here are the changes to the `daemonize` method:

```
def daemonize(self):
    ...

    # redirect standard file descriptors
    #sys.stdout.flush()
    #sys.stderr.flush()
    #si = open(self.stdin, 'r')
    #so = open(self.stdout, 'a+')
    #se = open(self.stderr, 'a+', 0)
    #os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
    #os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
    #os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

    print self.pool

    ...
```

Same thing, I am not redirecting io so that I can debug. The print here is used so that I can check the pools location.

And the `stop` method changes:

```
def stop(self):
    ...

    # Try killing the daemon process
    try:
        print self.pool
        print "closing pool"
        self.pool.close()
        print "joining pool"
        self.pool.join()
        print "set pool to None"
        self.pool = None
        while 1:
            print "kill process"
            os.kill(pid, SIGTERM)

    ...
```

Here the idea is that I not only need to kill the process but also clean up the pool. The `self.pool = None` is just a random attempt to solve the issues which didn't work. At first I thought this was a problem with zombie children which was occurring when I had the `self.pool.close()` and `self.pool.join()` inside the while loop with the `os.kill(pid, SIGTERM)`. This is before I decided to start looking at the pool location via the `print self.pool`. After doing this, I believe the pools are not the same when the daemon starts and when it stops. Here is some output:

```
me@pc:~/pyCode/jobQueue$ sudo ./jobQueue.py start
<multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x1c543d0>
me@pc:~/pyCode/jobQueue$ sudo ./jobQueue.py stop
<multiprocessing.pool.Pool object at 0x1fb7450>
closing pool
joining pool
set pool to None
kill process
kill process
... [ stuck in infinite loop]
```

The different locations of the objects suggest to me that they are not the same pool and that one of them is probably the zombie?

After `CTRL+C`, here is what I get from `ps aux|grep jobQueue`:

```
root     21161  0.0  0.0  50384  5220 ?        Ss   22:59   0:00 /usr/bin/python ./jobQueue.py start
root     21162  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    22:59   0:00 [jobQueue.py] <defunct>
me       21320  0.0  0.0   7624   940 pts/0    S+   23:00   0:00 grep --color=auto jobQueue
```

I have tried moving the `self.pool = Pool(processes=4)` to a number of different places. If it is moved to the `start()' or`daemonize()`methods,`print self.pool` will throw an exception saying that it is NoneType. In addition, the location seems to change the number of zombie process that will pop up.

Currently, I have not added the functionality to run anything via the workers. My problem seems completely related to setting up the pool of workers correctly. I would appreciate any information that leads to solving this issue or advice about creating a daemon service that uses a pool of workers to execute a series of commands using `Popen`. Since I haven't gotten that far, I do not know what challenges I face ahead. I am thinking I might just need to write my own pool but if there is a nice trick to make the pool work here, it would be amazing.

Comment: I think I have figured out what I need to do but I do not know how to do it. Inside the daemon, it writes to a pid file. Whenever start or stop is called, it gets the daemon's PID out of the file. I need to do the same with the PID of the pool process but how?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put the `self.pool = Pool(process=4)` as the last line of the `daemonize` method. Otherwise the pool ends up getting lost somewhere (perhaps in the `fork`s). Then the pool can be access inside the `run` method which is overloaded by the application you wish to daemonize. However, the pool cannot be accessed in the stop method and to do so would lead to NoneType exceptions. I believe there is a more elegant solution but this works and it is all I have for now. If I want the `stop` to fail when the pool is still in action, I will have to add additional functionality to `run` and some form of message but I am not currently concerned with this.

Comment: Ugh. It was actually quite simple, all I needed to do was put the `self.pool = Pool(process=4)` in the `run` method of the daemon but this still does not allow me to use the `close` `join` methods to cleanup the pool nicely. Any other solutions would be appreciated.